# Unable to update or install packages in Manjaro KDE

Tags: linux, installation, packages, manjaro

I did a fresh install of Manjaro KDE on one of my laptops. I have run Manjaro Xfce before, but I am a rather inexperienced user.

I tried to install some of my favorite packages using *Pamac 9.2.0-1* via the GUI. I can install most packages from the source *extra*, but I can not install anything from the AUR or the community source. The packages are all shown in the list, but the install operation fails, e.g. exiting like this:

```
[  8%] Built target libdxfrw
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Fehler 2
==> FEHLER: Ein Fehler geschah in build().
    Breche ab...
```

I also get the message, that some 200 packages have updates due, but I can not get install any of them. Trying it produces an output like below, basically saying, that I have an "Invalid or damaged package":

```
Synchronisiere Paketdatenbanken...
Vorbereitung...
Abhängigkeiten werden aufgelöst...
Interne Konflikte werden überprüft...
Warnung: Abhängigkeits-Zyklus entdeckt:
Warnung: mesa wird vor seiner Abhängigkeit libglvnd installiert werden
Warnung: Abhängigkeits-Zyklus entdeckt:
Warnung: lib32-mesa wird vor seiner Abhängigkeit lib32-libglvnd installiert werden
Herunterladen von libspiro (1:20190731-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von libspiro (1:20190731-1) beendet
Herunterladen von lensfun (0.3.2-9) gestartet
Herunterladen von lensfun (0.3.2-9) beendet
Herunterladen von metis (5.1.0.p7-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von metis (5.1.0.p7-1) beendet
Herunterladen von libgexiv2 (0.12.0-4) gestartet
Herunterladen von intel-tbb (2020.0-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von libgexiv2 (0.12.0-4) beendet
Herunterladen von intel-tbb (2020.0-1) beendet
Herunterladen von suitesparse (5.6.0-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von gegl (0.4.18-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von babl (0.1.72-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von gegl (0.4.18-1) beendet
Herunterladen von libheif (1.6.1-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von libheif (1.6.1-1) beendet
Herunterladen von libmypaint (1.4.0-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von libmypaint (1.4.0-1) beendet
Herunterladen von libwmf (0.2.12-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von babl (0.1.72-1) beendet
Herunterladen von libwmf (0.2.12-1) beendet
Herunterladen von suitesparse (5.6.0-1) beendet
Herunterladen von python2 (2.7.17-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von libglade (2.6.4-6) gestartet
Herunterladen von libglade (2.6.4-6) beendet
Herunterladen von python2-cairo (1.18.2-3) gestartet
Herunterladen von python2-cairo (1.18.2-3) beendet
Herunterladen von luajit (2.0.5-2) gestartet
Herunterladen von mypaint-brushes1 (1.3.0-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von luajit (2.0.5-2) beendet
Herunterladen von pygtk (2.24.0-8) gestartet
Herunterladen von python2-gobject2 (2.28.7-4) gestartet
Herunterladen von python2-gobject2 (2.28.7-4) beendet
Herunterladen von gimp (2.10.14-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von pygtk (2.24.0-8) beendet
Herunterladen von gutenprint (5.3.3-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von gutenprint (5.3.3-1) beendet
Herunterladen von poppler-glib (0.82.0-1) gestartet
Herunterladen von poppler-glib (0.82.0-1) beendet
Herunterladen von gimp (2.10.14-1) beendet
Herunterladen von mypaint-brushes1 (1.3.0-1) beendet
http://mirror.xeonbd.com/manjaro/stable/extra/x86_64/python2-2.7.17-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz: Zeitüberschreitung bei Ein-/Ausgabeoperation des Sockets
Herunterladen von python2 (2.7.17-1)...
Überprüfe Schlüsselring...
Integrität wird überprüft...
Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden:
Ungültiges oder beschädigtes Paket:
```

It appears to me like the package **libdxfrw** is broken or missing. I know, all these operations used to work on my old system. Is there anything I should do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check what is in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and use another mirror, the download of python2 failed:

```
http://mirror.xeonbd.com/manjaro/stable/extra/x86_64/python2-2.7.17-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz: Zeitüberschreitung bei Ein-/Ausgabeoperation des Sockets
```

or, you may follow here:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-update-libglvnd-mesa-give-errors-please-help-newbie/23856/17

```
sudo pacman-mirrors -g --country Germany
sudo pacman -Syyu --force
```

also you might check here:
https://wiki.manjaro.org/Pacman-mirrors#Switch_branch_to_unstable_and_use_German_mirrors

Comment: Thanks. I just found this issue myself and followed this description: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ungultiges-oder-beschadigtes-paket/114707. But your solution also works for me.